# Problem with switch dell 6224

Tags: networking, switch

we just have upgraded the firmware of a dell 6224 power connect switch and it won't reload.
  These are the symptons:
  - I power up the switch having the serial cable connected to it and the switch outputs nothing. The configuration of the serial console is fine:  9600 bds, etc... In fact, before the upgrade, I was connected to the switch through the very same cable.
  - Reseting the switch with its reset pinhole does not reset the switch: the power and fan lights powers off while I keep pressed the pinhole, but the switch itself does not resets.
  - When I connect an UTP cable to one of the switches port, the green lights don't flash, but ''mii-tool eth0'' in my laptop shows there is link!!

The only thing I see in the output, different from other upgrades I've done, is this line at the end:

Erasing Boot Flash.....^^^^Done.

Any help or idea will be more than welcome!!

Thanks!!

---

> console#show version
>
> Image Descriptions
>
> image1 :    image2 :
>
> Images currently available on Flash
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------  unit      image1      image2
>
> ### current-active        next-active
>
> ```
> 1      <none>     3.0.0.8             image2             image2
> ```
>
> console#boot system image2  Activating
>   image image2 ..
>
> console#update bootcode  Update
>   bootcode and reset (Y/N)?
>
> Updating boot code ...  Extracting
>   boot code from image... Erasing Boot
>   Flash.....^^^^Done.

---

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem you should talk to Dell about.

Call Dell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering!!
  We did exactly that. We contacted Dell's support here in Argentina and the next day they brought us a new switch. 
  Actually, we still don't know what the problem was, but the new switch runs very well :-) I upgraded it immediately and it is still working :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in all versions prior to 3.2.0.7. The workaround is not to use 'update bootcode' but to update the bootcode from the boot loader. Unfortunately, it was too late for your switch.